# Extract XSRF-TOKEN value from response cookie using bash

Tags: bash, curl, awk, sed

I am trying to extract the XSRF-TOKEN from the response cookie on a terminal.

```
$ curl -i http://localhost:8080/api/account | grep XSRF-TOKEN 

Output:

Set-Cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=8dbbc1b5-65e0-4b39-a0d9-81a4c3707eca; path=/
```

How can i extract the XSRF-TOKEN value from the above output? I want the output to be just **8dbbc1b5-65e0-4b39-a0d9-81a4c3707eca** and achieve it using single line of command.

AI tried it using jq -r to extract at least the value of Set-Cookie. But that did not work.

```
$ curl -i http://localhost:8080/api/account | grep XSRF-TOKEN |jq -r '.Set-Cookie'

Output:

jq: error: Cookie/0 is not defined at <top-level>, line 1:
.Set-Cookie     
jq: 1 compile error
```

Kindly help me with the bash/awk/sed command to extract the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
curl -i http://localhost:8080/api/account | sed -rn 's/(^.*XSRF-TOKEN=)(.*)(; path.*$)/\2/p'
```

Split the output of the curl command into three sections using regular expressions (sed -r) Substitute the line for the second section only and print.

Comment: Thank you for this sed command. In my case, path was with an uppercase P : "Path"